# Split a String by an indexes array

Tags: c#, strings

Let's say I have a plain text string that I want to split into a string array, using an integer array containing the indexes of this string where I want it to be cut.

Example:

Input string: `"001ABCD2T"`

Indexes array: `{3, 7, 8}`

Expected resulting string array: `{"001", "ABCD", "2", "T"}`

Here's how I do it for now:

```
string line = "001ABCD2T";
int[] markers = new int[] {3, 7, 8};

for (int i = -1; i < markers.Length; i++)
{
    string value = String.Empty;
    if (i == -1)
        value = line.Substring(0, markers[0]);
    else if (i == markers.Length - 1)
        value = line.Substring(markers[i], line.Length - markers[i]);
    else
        value = line.Substring(markers[i], markers[i + 1] - markers[i]);

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

The result is as expected, yet it is pretty eye-soring. Is there a cleaner way to write it, or even better, an already implemented method I didn't find?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not actually very familiar with C#. [I'll also refrain from the style review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/) and let someone more familiar with common practices take a crack.

You can prepend `0` and append `line.Length` to your array, simplifying the logic. There's probably a better way, but I got it working with a `List`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(0);
list.AddRange(markers);
list.Add(line.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string value = line.Substring(list[i], list[i + 1] - list[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Eh, that's an idea to start with, I like that. I'm waiting a bit for some other answers before accepting, but it already simplifies the code a lot.

Comment: @Kilazur No pressure to accept. In fact, accepting now may even discourage some people from writing more reviews, so by all means, leave it open!

Comment: No worries about that :p

Answer (score 9):

I would write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByIndex(this string @string, params int[] indexes)
    {
        var previousIndex = 0;
        foreach (var index in indexes.OrderBy(i => i))
        {
            yield return @string.Substring(previousIndex, index - previousIndex);
            previousIndex = index;
        }

        yield return @string.Substring(previousIndex);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (var part in "001ABCD2T".SplitByIndex(3, 7, 8))
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

Explanation:

It's better to encapsulate this splitting algorithm in a method so we can re-use the same code later from another place. I like to use extension methods for general-purpose methods like this. I usually implement such functionality in some common assembly in a separate namespace (for example, `MyCoolProject.Extensions.String`). This way, anyone who needs these extension methods can simply use the corresponding namespace in his code, and others will not be troubled by unnecessary methods.

As for the algorithm itself, it does not change our index array and it yields only one substring at a time. Plus, it's a bit more readable in my opinion because we do not use indexes to access index array; we're just iterating through it.

Comment: alright, why would you do that?

Comment: Given the context provided there is no reason to use an extension method.

Comment: `Would this answer constitute a reasonable checkin log message?` From [@200_Success's answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/18427)

Comment: @Malachi Well, if the OP's code is written at one place and needs to be moved so it can be reused, it could be an useful answer I think. But by itself, no I don't think it is a reasonable check in log message.

Comment: Why the `indexes.OrderBy(i => i)`? With that I'd expect the following to result in exactly the same: `"001ABCD2T".SplitByIndex(3, 7, 8)`, `"001ABCD2T".SplitByIndex(8, 3, 7)`, `"001ABCD2T".SplitByIndex(7, 8, 3)`; which is probably not how it should work.

Comment: @Corak How *should* that work? The original code doesn't handle those cases at all (it will throw an exception).

Comment: When you encounter invalid index, you should throw an exception, not just silently stop.

Comment: @Corak I do not see the difference between (3, 7, 8) and (8, 3, 7) to be honest

Comment: @svick Good point. I'll change the code

Comment: @RX_DID_RX - yes, sorry, I got that wrong. I completely misunderstood the question to mean to split after `3` and then after another `7` and then after another `8`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a forbidden token (cannot exist in the input string) is alright, here's a goofy idea idea using [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string line = "001ABCD2T";
int[] markers = { 3, 7, 8 };

const string tokenToSplitBy = "~";
int insertionCount = 0;

foreach (int index in markers)
    line = line.Insert(index + insertionCount++, tokenToSplitBy);

string[] resultArray = line.Split(new[]{tokenToSplitBy}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string result in resultArray)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Fancy and simple, dunno why I didn't think about that. Yet the performance will drop if I have to work with thousands of lines with great length :p But clever overall.

Comment: Agreed ... but the "something cleaner" challenge part of the question sort of de-prioritized the performance angle a bit.

Comment: Absolutely right, hence the appreciation; yet I hope you understand I will prefer an answer that fix my initial issue AND is optimization-friendly.

Comment: This way is really cute and I love it! Maybe I'll ask a candidate to explain what it does in a technical interview... `:-)`

Comment: Note that from a theoretical standpoint, this is going to be very inefficient (something like \$O(n^2)\$, when the original solution is \$O(n)\$). But I don't know whether this will affect actual performance, especially for small inputs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Once again, acknowledging that optimizing for performance was not entirely clear in the question; I chose to do something different (possibly fun!?)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see multiple calls to same method in if-else (or switch-case) sequence, I think about using few variables to make it single call. Conditional/ternary operator `?:` may as well be used instead of `if-else` (but some would not see that as readability enhancement).

```
string line = "001ABCD2T";
int[] markers = new int[] {3, 7, 8};

for (int i = -1, m = markers.Legth-1; i < markers.Length; i++)
{
    int from = i < 0 ? 0 : markers[i];
    int to = i == m ? line.Length : markers[i + 1];
    string value = line.Substring(from, to-from);

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

We can further think about rewriting it by remembering indexes from previous iteration:

```
for (int i = 0, from = 0; i <= markers.Length; i++)
{
    int to = i == markers.Length ? line.Length : markers[i];
    string value = line.Substring(from, to-from);
    from = to;

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Okay, what are we doing here and why?

Comment: The code should be clear enough for *what*, if you understand ternary operator. Why? It extractes the proper indexes (`from` and `to`) to use single call to `Substring`.

Comment: `Would this answer constitute a reasonable checkin log message?` From [@200_Success's answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/18427)

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question, I don't see how you can even think about that meta-post. I would never think about changing such code, because it works and is not slow. So, in short, I really don't see your point.

Comment: The quality of answers on our site matter. further discussion should be had in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without rebuilding the index array or any conditionals.  Simply handle the first substring and the last substring outside of the loop:

```
string line = "001ABCD2T";
int[] markers = new int[] { 3, 7, 8 };
List<string> output = new List<string>{line.Substring(0, markers[0])};;
int i = 0;
int limit = markers.Length - 1;
for (; i < limit; i++)
{
    output.Add(line.Substring(markers[i], markers[i + 1] - markers[i]));
}
output.Add(line.Substring(markers[i], line.Length - markers[i]));
```